# Is the Hamiltonian just a mnemonic for the Lagrangian?

Tags: calculus-of-variations, lagrange-multiplier, euler-lagrange-equation, hamilton-jacobi-equation

I've been studying the calculus of variations and optimal control theory, and I often read about the "Hamiltonian formalism".

I've been hearing about "Hamiltonian mechanics" for a while, and I don't really understand what the advantage is of Hamiltonian mechanics compared to Lagrangian mechanics.

**It always seemed to me that the Hamiltonian is just a different way of formulating the Lagrangian, without any real advantage.** This is ofcourse because of my ignorance, because if that were really true, it wouldn't be used.

---

However, now I'm reading a book that sort of suggests that the Hamiltonian is merely a "**mnemonic**", in order to better remember the optimality conditions for a variational problem.

The book defines the variational problem and the corresponding optimal control problem:

> [image]

Then it states the optimality conditions in terms of the Lagrangian:

> [image]

And finally, it states that conditions on the Hamiltonian are effectively mnemonics, to easier remember the conditions on the Lagrangian:

> [image]

---

**Is my interpretation correct that the Hamiltonian is merely a mnemonic for the Lagrangian? This seems absurd to me.**

Comment: I am not too familiar with optimal control, but, in mathematical physics, the Hamiltonian formalism is preferred due to its theoretical properties. In particular, the minimization of the action for a system with $n$ variables corresponds to solving $n$ second order differential equations. In contrast, the same problem in Hamiltonian mechanics corresponds to solving $2n$ coupled first order differential equations. The first order equations are more tractable theoretically.

Comment: Another advantage of Hamiltonian is that in a closed system, the value of Hamiltonian itself is constant, while Lagrangian is not.